# Carry domestic currency while going abroad

Tags: europe, money, international-travel, exchange

I am planning to fly from India to Europe this weekend for a one week holiday.
While departing from India, I'll have the Indian currency (INR) which I'll need to pay for things like taxi charges, some snacks at the airport.
Now I'll need some small amount of INR during my return to India as well (again for small expenses like  taxi charges, snacks, etc)

My question is can I carry the INR (very small amount like 3000 INR..approx 30-40 Euros) while flying to Europe (as I'll need them on returning to India)

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia, [Indian nationals can import or export up to 7500 INR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee#Convertibility) and foreign nationals none whatsoever. As far as European countries are concerned (certainly the one you mentioned in your other question), I don't think there are any limit but if you carry more than [10000 EUR (for the European Union)](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/customs/customs_controls/cash_controls/declaration_form/index_en.htm) or [10000 CHF (for Switzerland)](http://www.ezv.admin.ch/zollinfo_privat/04414/04415/index.html?lang=en), you have to declare it to the customs (this also covers any mix of foreign currency, bonds or shares worth as much).

Comment: Until recently foreign nationals were able to import Rupees. A change to 0 Rupees is very recent. For Indian nationals I heard a figure a few days ago of R150 (which is ludicrously small if true).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon That's straight from wikipedia, I have no idea if that's in line with current rules or practice. It seems there is a low limit in any case.